# Help with solution to complex quadratic equation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I'm learning about solving complex quadratic equations, in the examle I'm following, we start with:

$$z^2+4iz-(7+4i)=0$$

This can be rewritten as:

$$(z+2i)^2-(3+4i)=0$$

The square can be rewritten as $w^2$ so:

$$w^2=3+4i$$

Any complex number can be written on the form $a+bi $ so:

$$w^2=(a+bi)^2=a^2+2abi-b^2=3+4i$$

From this we learn that $2ab=4$ and that $a^2-b^2=3$ provided that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. I'm prepared to accept all of this, but the last part of the solution really bothers me.

According to my book the following applies:

$$x^2+y^2=|w|^2=|w^2|=|3+4i|=5$$

I can accept the first part, but why on earth would $|w|^2=|w^2|$?

This would mean that $a^2+b^2=a^2+2abi-b^2$, and why on earth would this be the case?

Also, why would $|w^2|=|3+4i|$?

If $|w^2|=|w|^2$ then by all rights, $|w^2|$ should equal $|3+4i|^2$?

Comment: Multiplying complex numbers, absolute values are multiplied, from where  $|w|^2=|w^2|.$

Comment: This is misinterpreted $a^2+b^2=a^2+2abi-b^2.$ Here RHS is not $|w|^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the modulus a complex numbers is multiplicative, if $w^2=z$, then $\;|z|=|w^2|=|w|^2$, so here
$$|z|=\sqrt{9+16\mathstrut}=5=a^2+b^2.$$
On the other hand, identifying real parts and imaginary parts, we obtain
\begin{cases}
a^2-b^2=3,\\
2ab=4.
\end{cases}
We'll determine $a^2$ and $b^2$, and deduce $a$ and $b$, taking into account that $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, by the last equation.
Adding and subtracting the first and second equation results in $$2a^2=8\iff a=\pm 4,\qquad 2b^2=2\iff b=\pm 1.$$
Therefore, as $a$ and $b$ have the same sign by the last equation, the square roots of  $3+4i$ are
$$a+ib=\pm(2+i).$$

Comment: Well sure but,,,I think I understand everything apart from that very first sentence which I feel like you'r rushing through.

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand ‘ the modulus is multiplicative ’?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing it has "something" to do with congruence (we rushed through that last chapter) but I have no idea how that is supposed to be applied to complex numbers, we haven't gone through that.

Comment: No, nothing to do with congruence. It corresponds to the well-known formula $\; |zz'|=|z|\,|z'|$.

Comment: I will have to look that up tomorrow. Does $z'$ refer to a derivative or is it just an arbitrary complex number?

Comment: It is just another complex number, possible equal to $z$.

Comment: Right, you arrive at the answer by proving that $|zw|=|z||w|$ and then setting $w=z$

Answer (score 1):

By the quadratic formula we get $$z_{1,2}=-2i\pm\sqrt{-4+7+4i}$$
Note that $$\sqrt{3+4i}=2+i$$

Comment: Isn't the radicand $3+4i$?

Comment: Yes it is just corrected! Thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

$$|(a+ib)|^2=a^2+b^2.$$

$$|(a+ib)^2|=|a^2-b^2+2iab|=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)+(2ab)^2}=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)^2}.$$